# If I launch this insert twice

Tags: sql

If I launch this insert twice, it adds duplicate products to me.
how do I add if something has changed?

```
INSERT INTO db1 ("Drink") VALUES
    ('Cola'),
    ('Rom'),
    ('Sprite'),
    ('Fanta'),
    ('Vodka');
```

Comment: Of course it'll add twice - try looking into [unique keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) - links to mysql, but the concept is the same regardless of flavour of SQL

Comment: db1 is a very poor _table_ name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO db1 ("Drink")
select
drinks.drink
from
(
VALUES
    ('Cola'),
    ('Rom'),
    ('Sprite'),
    ('Fanta'),
    ('Vodka')
)
as drinks(drink)
where not exists (select 1 from db1 where db1.drink=drinks.drink)
```

Comment: I'd argue this is not the best solution - namely because a the repertoire of items increases, so to will this query have to - please correct me if I'm wrong, but keys seem a better way to achieve the same result with less maintenance?

Comment: Hi, Yes, i interpreted it as "how do i stop this" not "what's the best way"  So i would expecting the whole `values(x,y,z)` to be a SQL statement or some user input.